# Display the conditionnal size of an array with the others fields of a mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of `fridges` and I would like to have some fields from each fridge matching a condition plus the 'conditionnal size' of the items in this fridge.

This is an example of my DB :

```
db={
  "fridges": [
    {
      _id: 1,
      items: [
        {
          itemId: 1,
          name:"beer"
        },
        {
          itemId: 2,
          name: "chicken"
        }
      ],
      brand:"Bosch",
      size:195,
      cooler:true,
      color:"grey"
    },
    
    {
      _id: 2,
      items: [
        {
          itemId: 1,
          name:"beer"
        },
        {
          itemId: 2,
          name: "chicken"
        },
        {
          itemId: 3,
          name: "lettuce"
        }
      ],
      brand:"Electrolux",
      size:200,
      cooler:true,
      color:"white"
    },
  ]
}
```

I want to get `fridges` with these mutuals conditions ('and' condition):

- `brand` is `$in ["Bosch","Samsung"]`
- `color` is `$in ["grey","white"]`

In addition :
The number of items with a name `$in ["beer","lettuce"]`

And finally :
Removing some fields like the `size` and `items` of the result.

In our example, the excepted output would be :

```
{
  _id:1
  itemsNumber:1,
  brand:"Bosch",
  cooler:true,
  color:"grey"
}
```

Explanations :
We removed the field `items` and `size`, `itemsNumber` counts the number of beers and lettuce from `items` array. And we only keep the first fridge its brand is Bosch and it's grey.

This what I have so far :

```
db.fridges.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $and: [
        {
          "brand": {
            $in: [
              "Bosch",
              "Samsung"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "color": {
            $in: [
              "grey",
              "white"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "itemsNumber": {
        $size: "$items" // This is not good
      },
      brand: 1,
      cooler: 1,
      color: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Which returns me :

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "brand": "Bosch",
    "color": "grey",
    "cooler": true,
    "itemsNumber": 2
  }
]
```

Counting the items matching with either `beer` or `lettuce` is my main problem.
[This](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4xsb24ekz3W) is an executable example.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried using `$filter`?

Comment: I am currently trying to use it but it is not working for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to make it work. Thank you @joe for suggesting to use filter this was indeed the solution.

Here is the complete query :

```
db.fridges.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "brand": {
            $in: [
              "Bosch",
              "Samsung"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "color": {
            $in: [
              "grey",
              "white"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "itemsNumber": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$items",
          "as": "item",
          "cond": {
            $in: [
              "$$item.name",
              [
                "beer",
                "lettuce"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      brand: 1,
      cooler: 1,
      color: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Runnable example.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N2i-qKiavvw)