# Comparing 2 fields from $project in a mongoDB pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68262648/display-the-conditionnal-size-of-an-array-with-the-others-fields-of-a-mongodb-do/68263032#68263032) I created a mongodb query projecting the number of elements matching a condition in an array. Now I need to filter this number of elements depending on another field.

This is my db :

```
db={
  "fridges": [
    {
      _id: 1,
      items: [
        {
          itemId: 1,
          name: "beer"
        },
        {
          itemId: 2,
          name: "chicken"
        }
      ],
      brand: "Bosch",
      size: 195,
      cooler: true,
      color: "grey",
      nbMax: 2
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      items: [
        {
          itemId: 1,
          name: "beer"
        },
        {
          itemId: 2,
          name: "chicken"
        },
        {
          itemId: 3,
          name: "lettuce"
        }
      ],
      brand: "Electrolux",
      size: 200,
      cooler: true,
      color: "white",
      nbMax: 2
    },
    
  ]
}
```

This is my query :

```
db.fridges.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "brand": {
            $in: [
              "Bosch",
              "Electrolux"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "color": {
            $in: [
              "grey",
              "white"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "itemsNumber": {
        $size: {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$items",
            "as": "item",
            "cond": {
              $in: [
                "$$item.name",
                [
                  "beer",
                  "lettuce"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      brand: 1,
      cooler: 1,
      color: 1,
      nbMax: 1
    }
  }
])
```

The [runnable](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cNP2pdOlCXS) example.

Which gives me this :

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "brand": "Bosch",
    "color": "grey",
    "cooler": true,
    "itemsNumber": 1,
    "nbMax": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "brand": "Electrolux",
    "color": "white",
    "cooler": true,
    "itemsNumber": 2,
    "nbMax": 2
  }
]
```

What I expect is to keep only the results having a `itemsNumber` different from `nbMax`. In this instance, the second fridge with `_id:2` would not match the condition and should not be in returned. How can I modify my query to get this :

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "brand": "Bosch",
    "color": "grey",
    "cooler": true,
    "itemsNumber": 1,
    "nbMax": 2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `$match` stage with expression condition at the end of your query,

- `$ne` to check both fields should not same

```
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: { $ne: ["$nbMax", "$itemsNumber"] }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gtfwxyG0y1R)